# Dataset usage in "MapGroupsWithState" of Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have events with `"id and Map[String, List]"` data. I'm grouping these data by `id`. Then I calculate somethings with "mapgroupswithstate".

Can I use `from_json()` method in `mapgroupswithstate`? So, can I use `dataset/dataframe` in `mapgroupswithstate`?

For example;

```
df.groupBy().mapgroupswithstate{
   val anotherDF = events.toDF
   ... other operations...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I use from_json() method in mapgroupswithstate? So, can I use dataset/dataframe in mapgroupswithstate?

Ans - Answer to both questions is No (loosely). Not in a standard way. 
When you are operating within mapgroupswithstate, then you are entering to executor level operations where you can write you custom code without dataframe abstraction.

Comment: Also, I wanna ask one more question. When I use mapgroupswithstate without "timeout"(also it's update mode), Will state grow infinitly? For example I have 100 user, and I keep 100 state for these users. Each state will be updated with each received data. In this case, all states grow infinitly?

Comment: Without timeout, updates to each group's state should be saved across invocation of the streaming query. I haven't tried it personally.